# Why is the if statement under this else if executing?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've been trying to figure this out for a while. For some reason, the first if statement under the

else if(customerType = "T")

keeps executing even if customerType is not equal to "T", so discountPercent keeps becoming .40 no matter what the input is unless customerType is equal to either "R", "C", or "T". Can anyone help me out?

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculate_click = function () {
var customerType = $("type").value.toUpperCase;
var invoiceSubtotal = parseFloat( $("subtotal").value );
$("subtotal").value = invoiceSubtotal.toFixed(2);
var discountPercent = .0;
var valid = false;

if (customerType == "R") {
    valid = true;
    if (invoiceSubtotal < 100){
        discountPercent = .0;
    }
    else if (invoiceSubtotal >= 100 && invoiceSubtotal < 250){
        discountPercent = .1;
    }
    else if (invoiceSubtotal >= 250 && invoiceSubtotal < 500){
        discountPercent = .25;
    }
    else if (invoiceSubtotal >= 500){
        discountPercent = .30;
    }
}

else if (customerType == "C") {
    valid = true;
    discountPercent = .20;
    }

else if (customerType = "T"){
    valid = true;
    if(invoiceSubtotal < 500){
        discountPercent = .40;
    }
    if(invoiceSubtotal >= 500){
        discountPercent = .50;
    }
}

else if(!valid){
    discountPercent = .10;
}

var discountAmount = invoiceSubtotal * discountPercent;
var invoiceTotal = invoiceSubtotal - discountAmount;

$("percent").value = (discountPercent * 100).toFixed(2) ;
$("discount").value = discountAmount.toFixed(2);
$("total").value = invoiceTotal.toFixed(2);

$("type").focus;
}
```

Comment: you are assigning `"T"` to customer type. Might i suggest a `switch`?

Comment: You probably mean else if (customerType == "T")

Comment: Thank you, these errors always drive me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else if (customerType = 'T')` always evaluates to `true` because it is not comparing anything, it is assigning the 'T' value to customerType.

Maybe you wanted to do `else if (customerType == 'T')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant:

```
else if (customerType == "T")
                      ^
                typo here corrected
```

Because

```
else if (customerType = "T")
```

is the exact same as:

```
else if ("T")
```

"T" being evaluating to true, this statement will always be true no matter what.